# Django-Oscar un-registering a class from admin panel

Tags: django, django-oscar

I would like to **un-register** a ModelAdmin class from the default oscar app.

I created an admin.py file and did the following but was unable to obtain the desired result.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from oscar.apps.address.admin import *

admin.site.unregister(UserAddressAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(CountryAdmin)
```

The model is still displayed in the admin panel.

I want the model to be created but I do not want to display the same in the admin panel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`admin.site.unregister` takes the `Model` class that you want to unregister - you are passing it a `ModelAdmin` class, which it will just ignore. This should work:

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_model

admin.site.unregister(get_model('address', 'useraddress'))
admin.site.unregister(get_model('address', 'country'))
```

*However this is all unnecessary!* Why don't you just put an empty `admin.py` file in your fork of the app? Currently you are importing Oscar's admin registrations only to manually unregister all of them again. Just don't import them.

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke :) 

Taking help from your answer and [here](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.1/topics/fork_app.html) I was able to achieve what I wanted.